# Can anyone recommend a good pdf/word conveter for a list item and lib (SP 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, pdf

Looking or a way to convert picture,document libraries and list to pdf document.
So a user can select this option from the list menu.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the following in SharePoint Foundation production environments. It has both a ribbon action and a SharePoint Designer Workflow activity.

http://sp2010wordautomation.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PDF Converter for SharePoint](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx). It can convert many common, and some uncommon, file types to PDF [including entire SharePoint pages](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/convert-html-pages-to-pdf-format-using.html).

Works from the SharePoint User Interface, [SharePoint Designer](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/04/using-pdf-converter-from-sharepoint.html) and [Nintex workflows](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/12/converting-multiple-files-to-pdf-format.html) as well as your own code [via web service calls](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html).

Does a lot of extra stuff as well including [PDF Merging](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2011/05/converting-and-merging-multiple-files.html), [watermarking](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/10/watermarking-features-of-muhimbi-pdf.html), [securing](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/12/securing-pdf-files-using-sharepoint.html) etc.

[Cross conversion](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2012/02/convert-document-types-using-pdf.html) (InfoPath to Word / Excel, Excel to Word, Word to Excel) is possible as well.

Please note that I worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.